# The string constant beginning with "')" does not have an ending string delimiter

Tags: sql, database

I design a in-emp.sql to prompt the user to input employee data but it shows ERROR near line 11:
SQL0010N  The string constant beginning with "')" does not have an ending string delimiter.
What should I do to fix this issue?

in-emp.sql

```
prompt 'Entry for employee table'
prompt

accept v_emp_id     format a5   prompt 'Employee ID: '
accept v_emp_name   format a25  prompt 'Employee Name: '
accept v_address    format a50  prompt 'Address: '
accept v_tel_no     format a14  prompt 'Tel No: '
accept v_dob                prompt 'Date (yyyy-mm-dd): '
accept v_stor_id    format a4   prompt 'Store ID: '

insert into employee values
('&v_emp_id,'&v_emp_name','&v_address','&v_tel_no','&v_dob','&v_stor_id');
```

cre-emp.sql

```
drop table employee;

create table employee (
emp_id      varchar(5)  not null,
emp_name    varchar(25),
address     varchar(50),
tel_no      varchar(14),
dob     date,
stor_id     varchar(4),
primary key (emp_id),
foreign key (stor_id) references stores(stor_id),
constraint yeardob check (year(dob) < 1996)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a missing ' - this is better:

```
insert into employee values
('&v_emp_id','&v_emp_name','&v_address','&v_tel_no','&v_dob','&v_stor_id');
           ^
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw, is that any software can be used to check the error?

Comment: I don't think so. Computers are dumb. But normally the error sits in front of the screen :D

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I had the weirdest case where inserting `'ðasdf'` worked, but `'asðdf'` didn't. If `ð` (unicode character) was too close to the closing single quotes, I got this error.

This happened with DB2 database and a `VARCHAR(255)` column.

It was because I had the file in the wrong encoding (`Cp1252`). Encoding the file as `utf8` fixed this.